# Mysql Average of distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know if it's possible if I could do this:

I have this table:

| Customer | Week | SoldUnits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 1 | 24 |
| C1 | 2 | 17 |
| C1 | 3 | 52 |
| C2 | 1 | 18 |
| C2 | 2 | 65 |
| C2 | 3 | 12 |
| C2 | 4 | 33 |
| C3 | 1 | 18 |
| C3 | 2 | 65 |

And I want to calculate the average of the last 2 weeks available of every customer. For example, I have to return this table:

| Customer | AverageSoldUnits |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | 34.5 |
| C2 | 22.5 |
| C3 | 41.5 |

The trick is that not every customer has the same max Week.

Comment: Please elaborate on your MySql verion

Comment: So you just need to know how to get the last two rows for each customer, right? Once you do that, you just use `AVG()` and `GROUP BY Customer`